# elseif only displaying 2 images

Tags: php, mysql, database, if-statement

Okay so I have radio buttons for the user to pick from certain images as their image. Their image starts as the default image and can change it to 2 others. Here's the radio buttons and PHP to display the image:

```
    <input type="radio" id="Default" name="change_image" value="0" />
    <input type="radio" id="Unknown" name="change_image" value="1" />     
    <input type="radio" id="Gasmask" name="change_image" value="2" />     

    <?php 
if ( $user_image < 1 )
{
    echo 
    '<img src="images/user_image/Default.png" width="60" height="60" />';
} 
elseif ( $user_image = 1 )
{
    echo 
    '<img src="images/user_image/Unknown.png" width="60" height="60" />';
}
elseif ( $user_image > 1 )
{
    echo 
    '<img src="images/user_image/GasMask.png" width="60" height="60" />';
}
?>
```

Well, the if and first elseif work, but the 3rd elseif will not display that image? Are their any reasons why?

Comment: `elseif ( $user_image = 1 )` ... you should have two equal signs, i.e. `$user_image == 1`; or use Yoda syntax `elseif (1 = $user_image)` would throw an error :)

Comment: Ah, thank you. Didn't know that before. It fixed it right away! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is due to your second elseif.

```
elseif ( $user_image = 1 )
```

Where you should be testing for equality, you are instead assigning the value of 1 into $user_image. Try replacing it with:

```
elseif ( $user_image == 1 )
```

Answer (score 4):

You used `=` which is an assignment statement instead of a comparison statement. Use `==` to compare!

Also, what you're doing seems a little overhead (to me, I'm no expert though), but please note I cannot see how you handle `$user_image`. Here is how I would do it:

```
<input type="radio" id="Default" name="change_image" value="Default" />
<input type="radio" id="Unknown" name="change_image" value="Unknown" />     
<input type="radio" id="Gasmask" name="change_image" value="Gasmask" />     

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['change_image'])) { //make sure you validate that the right stuff is being posted
    $user_image = $_POST['change_image'];
    echo "<img src='images/user_image/".$user_image.".png' width='60' height='60' />";
}
```

I haven't tested to see if the variable is concatenated properly, but that will save you many if statements so long as you follow the convention of the name being the value of the radio button. I hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for giving both the solution and a better methodology.

Answer (score 2):

you are assigning in if condition man use double equal

```
if ( $user_image < 1 )
{
    echo 
    '<img src="images/user_image/Default.png" width="60" height="60" />';
} 
elseif ( $user_image == 1 )
{
    echo 
    '<img src="images/user_image/Unknown.png" width="60" height="60" />';
}
```

Comment: You are right, but the second one is working for him

Comment: @Eritrea Of course the second one is working, because it would always work as long as the value is >= 1.